# Any way to cout in base64?

Tags: c++, string, base64, radix, cout

I know I could use itoa to create a base64 string, just wondered if there was an easy way to cout a number in base64 the same way cout << hex sets a flag to display integral values in hex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way (`setbase` only accepts 8, 10, 16 as parameters). You'll have to write your own stream manipulator.

Comment: I don't think you can simply write it as a manipulator as you can't store any custom state in standard library streams.  You can, however, implement some `class ob64stream` deriving from `std::ostream` and matching `class b64streambuf` to achieve it, I think.  I've seen some compressing streams written this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old code but valid [xstreambuf](http://xstream.sourceforge.net/)